# Function parameters order in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

I have this code in one of my PowerShell scripts:

```
function callCommandWithArguments([String] $arg1, [String] $arg2)
{
    [string]$pathToCommand = "C:\command.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "anArg", "-other", "$arg2", "$arg1";
# the real code is
#   & $pathToCommand $arguments;
# but was not working, so I change it to debug
    Write-Host $pathToCommand $arguments;
}

callCommandWithArguments("1", "2");
```

As the arguments order is changed in the `$arguments` array, I would expect this output:

```
C:\command.exe anArg -other  2 1
```

But instead I receive a strange:

```
C:\command.exe anArg -other  1 2
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try call your function like this:

```
callCommandWithArguments "1" "2"
```

In powershell you pass arguments to function without `()` and just separated by space.

In your code you  are passsing a single argument  array of type `object[]`